# How to add a ghostly "Glow" effect?

Tags: light, compositing-nodes, effects

I want to add an "aura" effect to objects. I tried adding blur nodes in the compositor but it didn't look right. I also thought about using layer weights and with fresnel to make the edges glow. Then after watching [Coco](https://letterboxd.com/film/coco-2017/) for the bazillionth time — the scene where Miguel sees his dead family — I liked the way the light surrounds each person.

[image: See the way the edges of his family members, including Miguel, have glow effect]

Comment: Looks like characters are rendered separately in a different layer or ID and a mask is extracted from their outline that is then used to add some sort of glow in post production

Comment: I like where  Duarte Farrajota Ramos is going... Definately some Post... but a glow layer and some emission materials in Cycles will come very close. I'm guessing the darks of the hair and eyes are composited over.

Answer (score 9):

**Create a Glow Layer**

You separate your render into two, the normal render and a glow render, both layers with a transparent background, in the glow layer set all the objects to have the same material (use an emission shader with the color of the glow you want):

[image]
[image]

Then, you can use this Node Setup in the Compositor:

[image]
[image]

You have to take into account that, in this example, the lighting is lame, that's why the effect doesn't look realistic, but using the same lighting that your scene will give you great results