# How to get outer glow to the object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I have a node setup and got this effect.

[image]

**Node setup**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

Need to have a outer glow to the object like this

**Outer Glow**

[image]

What extra node i have to add to get the above result to glow my object. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a Ghost Type Effect?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114698/how-to-add-a-ghost-type-effect)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos yes i need that effect but cant it be before jumping to compositing

Comment: Could you explain why you want to avoid compositing? That might throw up some interesting answers?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88584/creating-a-planet-atmosphere-blurry-edge/88602#88602 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88613/problem-with-id-mask-and-glow-effect/88662#88662

Comment: For that you may need to create passes.

Answer (score 2):

Create a box.
*Create a new shader for the box
*Unplug material from material output. 
*Create a new principled volume shader
*Connect it to VOLUME on material output
*turn density to 0.02
*Play with absorption.

Put the box enclosing the monkey.

Volume shading will capture light by the absorption and density parameter.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you plz share the nodes how it works and show in detail

Answer (score 1):

You have to render the image and then you switch to the compositing tab and then add in the filter glare and change it from streaks to fog glow and then you can tweak it.[image]

Comment: But i cant change the color of the glow

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the new Cryptomatte feature in 2.8 which will allow you to separate objects or materials in your render, I'm not very familiar with it myself yet but here is a quick test I did to get a soft glow around an object with the option to change it's color. Check out this video for more tips on how to use the Cryptomatte.    https://youtu.be/Ml1Kic4VopA.  [image]